# Jest: How to mock db response from controller?

Tags: node.js, express, jestjs

I am learning unit testing. I wanted to mock the database response from the controller.
How can I do that?
here is my code:

imageController.ts

```
 const getImages = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const images = await Image.find({}).sort({ date: -1 });
  return res.status(200).json(images);
};
```

image.test.ts

```
describe("It shuld be get methoad", () => {
  test("get all image url", async () => {
    const res = await request(app).get("/api/v1/all");
    expect(res.statusCode).toBe(200);
    // console.log(res.body);
    let images = res.body
    // expect(images.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using Mongoose, so I would suggest using a nice and quite popular library for mocking Mongoose: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mockingoose

Comment: after installing @types/mockingoose, not supported in typescript. it shows this message----- Could not find a declaration file for module 'mockingoose'. '/home/imran/Practice/jest-ts/node_modules/mockingoose/lib/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/mockingoose` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'mockingoose';`

Comment: @AlImranHossain yes, just run `npm i --save-dev @types/mockingoose` to install the declaration files for TS to understand the module.

Comment: applied but not work. same message show

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution using the [mongodb-memory-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb-memory-server) package.

```
import request from "supertest";
import app from "../src/app";
import { MongoMemoryServer } from "mongodb-memory-server";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import { fakeImage, fakeAddImage } from "../src/utils/data";
import Image from "../src/models/image";

describe("Image CRUD operation test", () => {
  //For mocking db
  beforeAll(async () => {
    const mongoServer = await MongoMemoryServer.create();

    await mongoose.connect(mongoServer.getUri());
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    await mongoose.disconnect();
    await mongoose.connection.close();
  });


  it("should return a 200 & get image by id", async () => {
    const image = await Image.create(fakeImage);
    console.log("image", image);

    const { body, statusCode } = await request(app).get(
      `/api/v1/image/${image._id}`
    );
    // console.log("body", body);
    expect(statusCode).toBe(200);
    expect(body.data.title).toBe(image.title);
  });
});
```